# Getting a segfault working with arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, segmentation-fault

I'm in an introductory C++ class, so I'm totally new to this, but I seem to be getting a segfault at runtime with the following code (stripped down to about where I think the problem is):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
string filename;
ifstream infile;
float average;
int const ARRAY_SIZE = 20;
int count = 0;
string responses[ARRAY_SIZE];
string response;
char grade;

welcome();
splash();

cout << showpoint << setprecision(1) << fixed;

cout << "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
     << "\t\tEnter 8-Ball response file name: ";
cin  >> filename;

infile.open(filename.c_str());
system("CLS");
        cout << "score";
cout << "\n\n\n\n";

if (infile)
    {
        while (!infile.eof())
        {
            infile >> response;
            if (1==1)
            {
                responses[count] = response;
                count ++;
            }

        }
            infile.close();
    }

cout << "\n\n\n";

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

There's some extra lines, variables, etc. in there just because this was thrown together from various old programs, and I didn't include the functions because that's not where the problem seems to be. Basically, whenever I enter a file name, I get a segfault. It prints "score", so it's after that point, and I tried taking out the if portion, but it still gave me grief, so it appears that the issue is with the code in the while statement.
We haven't gone over segfaults in any kind of detail, so I don't even know  where to begin searching for the issue.

Comment: `while (!infile.eof())` is wrong, it should be `while (infile >> response)`. What happens if your file contains more than 20 responses? Instead of hardcoding the array to some arbitrary size, you should use `std::vector<std::string>` which expands in size as required. If this is what you are taught in your class, it is a very bad class I'm afraid.

Comment: Have you gone over using a debugger to step through your program, so you can see where the error happened?  Segfaults generally come from misusing pointers or writing outside the bounds of an array.

Comment: @neil-kirk Yeah, that's what we've been taught. This teacher's been kinda flaky about quite a few things, so I can't say I'm totally shocked to hear that we've learned things the wrong way. Luckily there's only a few weeks left. Looks like the first suggestion you made is mostly a drop-in replacement, but what exactly do I do with the second?

Comment: Aha Steephen has beaten me to it. He shows how to use the vector. You can also use push_back instead of emplace_back if not supported by your compiler. You no longer need to keep a count variable, as you can use `responses.size()` to get the number.

Answer (score 2):

You hard coded array size, and is there any chance it is crossing that limit?

So if your responses can grow dynamically, declare a vector as follows

`#include<vector>
std::vector<std::string> responses;`

And correct your loop as follows:

```
   while (infile >> response;)
    {         
         responses.emplace_back(response);
         count ++;       

    }
     infile.close();
```

Comment: Thanks a bundle. Should I put the "std..." line up with the rest of my variables? It's giving me `error: ‘vector’ is not a member of ‘std’`


Edit: Oh, and in this case, the number of responses _is_, in fact, hardcoded. Definitely should have mentioned sooner.

Comment: If you are using using namespace std; already I assume so, you don't need. But using std::string is better approach than using namespace std;

Comment: To resolve the error, you should add  #include<vector> I added into answer